# Making dictionary from 2 lists

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, arraylist

I have following two lists:

```
list1 = ['17-Q2', '1.00', '17-Q3', '2.00', '17-Q4', '5.00', '18-Q1', '6.00']
list2 = ['17-Q2', '1', '17-Q3', '2', '17-Q4', '5', '18-Q1', '6']
```

I want a dictionary in the following way. Can I do that in Python?

```
result = [17-Q2: 1(1.00), 17-Q3: 2(2.00), 17-Q4: 5(5.00), 18-Q1: 6(6.00)]
```

Comment: Are both the lists of same length? And your result doesn't seem to look like a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach to this:

```
result = {}
list1=['17-Q2', '1.00', '17-Q3', '2.00', '17-Q4', '5.00', '18-Q1', '6.00']
list2=['17-Q2', '1', '17-Q3', '2', '17-Q4', '5', '18-Q1', '6']

for i in range(0, len(list1)-1, 2):
    result[list1[i]] = list2[i + 1] + '(' + list1[i+1] + ')' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input to be as follows:

```
list1 = ['17-Q2', '1.00', '17-Q3', '2.00', '17-Q4', '5.00', '18-Q1', '6.00']
list2 = ['17-Q2', '1', '17-Q3', '2', '17-Q4', '5', '18-Q1', '6']
```

And Desired Output to be as follows:

```
result = {17-Q2: 1(1.00), 17-Q3: 2(2.00), 17-Q4: 5(5.00), 18-Q1: 6(6.00)}
```

Following code with a single `while` loop could help:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
final_dict = dict()
i = 0 # Initializing the counter

while (i<len(list1)):
      # Updating the final dict
      final_dict.update({list1[i]:str(list2[i+1]) + "(" + str(list1[i+1]) + ")"})
      i += 2 # Incrementing by two in order to land on the alternative index

# If u want sorted dictionary
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(final_dict.items()))
print (sorted_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the two lists and then `zip` the resulting iterable with itself so that you can iterate through it in pairs to construct the desired dict:

```
i = zip(list1, list2)
result = {k: '%s(%s)' % (v2, v1) for (k, _), (v1, v2) in zip(i, i)}
```

`result` becomes:

```
{'17-Q2': '1(1.00)', '17-Q3': '2(2.00)', '17-Q4': '5(5.00)', '18-Q1': '6(6.00)'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-dict).

```py
keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
values = ["A", "B", "C"]

print(dict(zip(keys, values)))
# prints: {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}
```

This works because `dict` can take a list (or any iterator) of tuples of `(key, value)` to be created. The `zip` function allows to build tuples from lists:

> `zip` returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

Notice that this will only return a dictionary that pairs the shortest list (either `keys` or `value`) with the corresponding element.

If you wish to have a default value for unpaired elements you can always use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
values = ["A", "B", "C"]

print(dict(zip_longest(keys, values)))
# prints: {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C', 'd': None}
```

You can also use `zip_longest` keyword parameter `fillvalue` to have something else than `None` when the corresponding value isn't found.

On the other hand, if you have more values than keys, this wouldn't make much sense as you would erase the default key (namely `fillvalue`) for every missing element.